# If I preload an image using javascript will it then be loaded when I use it in a <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, preload

I had an issue with small images loading very slowly so I figured I should try to preload it to the browser cache. I looked it up and found numerous ways to asynchronously preload the images but two things remained unclear.
Let's say I have an array of images file names (assume each element is the correct full path)

```
const images = ['img1.png','img2.png','img3.png']
```

I preload the images using what I've learned from [Preloading Images with JavaScript](https://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/javascript-image-preload)

```
function preLoad(){
  images.forEach(img => {
    const myImage = new Image()
    myImage.onload = (img) => myImage.src = img
  })
}
preload()
```

Note that I didn't store any of the images objects in a variable or an array.
After the process is done, are the images cached and ready to use just by referencing the file name? For example if I tried to

```
document.getElementById('image-container').innerHTML = `<img src="${images[0]}" alt="${images[0]}>`
```

Will it show the image immediately? And since this method doesn't use any of the asynchronous methods (callback, promises, async/await), How can I know the process is done and the images are ready to be used?

Comment: Well ordering is an issue, what if the image tag is added before the "pre-load" returns? IMO pre-loading is a waste of time. It adds complexity for little benefit. this is the kind of thing people used to do in the days of 56k modems. In 2020 it's pretty useless. If your images are that large that they take too long to load, you've got bigger problems. Spend you time optimising your images/design instead of doing this

Comment: Your preload script is a little odd. Most of the time you'd just do `myImage.src = img;`. The point is just to create an `Image` object with the right `src` so that the cache gets the downloaded image. Considering the `myImage` does not have a `src` at first, I'm not sure why the `onload` event would fire.

Comment: @HereticMonkey So the that line should be just  `myImage.src = img` and the image will be cached? The code itself is from the link I've provided but I had no use for the notify function.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read the article, I'm just speaking from experience. When I was doing preloading, I'd just iterate over the array, creating new `Image` objects with the source set. This was before `rel="preload"` was available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue once and have posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976479/why-sometimes-does-the-img-jump-in-this-blackjack-game/61751679#61751679).
I used `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="cards/PNG/2C.png">`  to achieve preloading.

I imagine your JavaScript function does the same. If so what happens is that the browser loads all the images before it displays the page and therefore it can display the images without interruption.

To be able to check if that's really what's happening "Inspect" your page and in the sources tab you should be able to see all the files the browser has loaded up including your images and it uses the same file hierarchy as you did in your code.